# react RTK app mock API call throwing error related to reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am building a react app using RTK and getting below error when I import mock api to the app.

**> redux.js:426 Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.**

[image: the error message which I am getting]

my code is as below. if any one can tell me what am I doing wrong here would be useful for me to update myself.

---

app js

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLorems());
  }, []);
 
  const lorem = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(lorem, "lorem");

  return (
    <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(lorem)}</div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

slice

---

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getLorems = createAsyncThunk(
  "getLorems",
  async (object, { getState, rejectWithValue }) => {
    console.log(getState());
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "api goes here"
      );
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      rejectWithValue(error.response);
    }
  }
);

const loremSlice = createSlice({
  name: "lorem",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    message: "",
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getLorems.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getLorems.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = payload;
      state.isSuccess = true;
    },
    [getLorems.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.message = "failed";
    },
  },
});

export default loremSlice;
```

---

i tried adding api and try to fetch data to redux and then dispaly in app

Answer (score 0):

The object notation in `extraReducers` has been marked deprecated for a while and had a warning in the docs that it would be removed, you should really use the builder syntax.

```js
const loremSlice = createSlice({
  name: "lorem",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    message: "",
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getLorems.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getLorems.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.data = payload;
        state.isSuccess = true;
      })
      .addCase(getLorems.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.message = "failed";
      });
  },
});
```